# How to use ajaxUserCall function in Jquery Validation Plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, jquery-plugins

I am try to use Jquery Validation Plugin in asp.net(C#) application with webservice
[https://jqueryvalidation.org/]
There is a custom ajax method called ajaxUserCall but i have no idea on how to use this function.
Here is a snapshot of how this method should work.
Any suggestion will be help full
[ajaxUserCall in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPzrU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="user" name="user" type="text" class="validate[required,ajax[ajaxUserCall]]" />
```

In your validationEngine js file:

```
"ajaxUserCall": {
    "url": "ajaxValidateFieldUser",
    "extraData": "name=eric",
    "extraDataDynamic": ['#user_id', '#user_email'],
    "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
    "alertTextOk": "All good!",
    "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
},
```

- url - the remote restful service to call
- extraData - optional parameters to send
- extraDataDynamic - optional DOM id's that should have their values sent as parameters
- alertText - error prompt message if validation fails
- alertTextOk - optional prompt if validation succeeds (shows green)
- alertTextLoad - message displayed while the validation is being performed

Comment: I am a bit confused at "url"(which points to webMethod in webservices).should this webMethod return true/False or any other datatype....!!

Comment: "_ajax" in "jquery.validationEngine.js" has a success method which are expecting return value like "errorFieldId" and so on...what should i do about those...

Comment: Sorry, according to [this demo](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/demos/phpajax/ajaxValidateFieldUser.php), looks like it expects back an array with the control ID and a success/fail boolean.

Comment: thank!! that demo was helpful...It seems that i have run into another problem ..on success of the ajax method entire [document] is being return rather than the return values of webmethod

Comment: That sounds like a different question related to your server implementation. I'd post it separately with some server code as a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you so much...for your suggestion and especially the demo....i was making some silly mistake but it worked

Comment: Can i pass three Parameter in "extraDataDynamic"??